# What dialect is ！〜べ?

Tags: dialects, auxiliaries, modality

What dialect is それはねぇべ （それはないだろう）?

It seems I hear it a lot from people from Chiba. Is it from a specific part of Chiba or even a wider area?

Comment: It doesn't mean それはないよ but それはないだろう.

Comment: @user4092 Good call. Edited

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's widely used in Kanto and Tohoku regions to a varying degree. Stereotyped Tohoku dialect uses っぺ instead of べ(ー), though.

> #### [東京方言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E8.A1.A8.E7.8F.BE)
>
> 伝統的な関東方言・東北方言では意思・同意・推量の語尾は「べ（え）」であり、「行くべ」や「これだべ」「これだんべ」「これだっぺ」などと言うが、東京方言では「行こう」や「これだろ（う）」と言う。「う・よう」の使用が広まる以前は江戸でも「べ（え）」を多用し、当時上方の人間から「関東べい」と呼ばれていた。